# How to output the number of characters if at least 10

Tags: assembly, lc3

Basically the code is meant to take some user input, and output how many total characters there are, but as soon as it gets to 10, it prints the ascii character instead of the actual number of characters that were inputted.

I know that I need to subtract 10 from the total count and for each 10 subtracted, add 1 to another register or variable and print this as the 10s value, but can't quite figure out how to set this up. I'm completely new to this but have tried a few other things, but I didn't completely understand what I was doing so can't really explain them. It currently prints the number of characters if 9 or less.Yes I'm well aware that this is likely very terrible code, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
.orig x3000

;clear registers
and r0, r0, 0
and r1, r1, 0  
and r2, r2, 0           
and r3, r3, 0           
and r4, r4, 0           
and r5, r5, 0
and r6, r6, 0
and r7, r7, 0           

Lea r0, EnterString         
puts                

LOOP                
    getc                
    add r1, r0, -10         
    brz END_LOOP            

    add r2, r2, #1          

    out                 
    brnzp LOOP          

END_LOOP            

Lea r0, NumTens
puts

NEXTLOOP
    add r2, r2, -10     
    brn END_NEXTLOOP    

    add r3, r3, #1      
    brzp NEXTLOOP       
END_NEXTLOOP

Lea r0, NumChar         
puts

ld r7, NumTensTotal
add r7, r7, r3

ld r0, compCharTotalOnes
add r0, r0, r2
out

Lea r0 FinSen
puts

Halt

EnterString .stringz "\nPlease enter a text: "
NumTens .stringz "\n"
NumChar .stringz "Totally, it has "
NumTensTotal .fill x30
compCharTotalOnes .fill x30
FinSen .stringz " characters including spaces"

.end
```

If the user inputs: "Stack Overflow", the program should say there is 14 total characters.

Comment: The usual algorithm for int->ASCII decimal string is *division* by 10 (and the remainder is the least-significant digit).  Yes you can do division by repeated subtraction.  If your number can be more than 2 decimal digits long, you have to repeat the process to split the quotient.  e.g. [Algorithm to convert integer between bases using LC-3 Assembly Language](//stackoverflow.com/q/16379886) shows how to convert a binary integer to base 10 ASCII.

Comment: It looks like your code is (trying to) implement the right algorithm.  (`NumTens` is an insane variable name for a `"\n"`, though, and IDK why you need two vars in memory holding `0x30` when you could just use that as an immediate operand.  And write it as `'0'` if your assembler allows that.)  What do you actually get as output?  (required part of a [mcve])  And have you single-stepped it with a debugger to see where it goes wrong?

Comment: @PeterCordes Our teacher's English is terrible ans so are her notes, so I've just been using trial and error then going with the first thing that works. Currently for output if there is 9 or less characters it will print 0-9 correctly, but anything greater doesn't output properly, so for example 18 characters will output 'B'. It only has to go up to 99 characters, and starting out, repeated subtraction seemed like it would be an easier concept to implement.

Comment: It sounds like you forgot to take the remainder for the low digit, because `'0' + 18 == 'B'` in ASCII.  And maybe you forgot to add `'0'` (i.e. 0x30) to the 10s place, so it was a byte value that represents a non-printable ASCII character.